# how to get drop location using request id after trip is completed

Tags: android, location, uber-api

in **GET/history** endpoint I am getting details about previous trips but I am only getting start location. So my question is how to get the drop location?
I am also tried **GET/requests/{request_id}** endpoint using the request_id which I am getting from **GET/history** but as the trip is COMPLETED I am not able to get the drop location, driver details etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get the destination after the trip is over.

Comment: Dustin thax for ur response